# How to use getParameter() in Struts 2 tag?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl, ognl

I want to get a variable that I search in JSP, something like this

```jsp
<s:textfield value="<%=request.getParameter("id")%>" />
```

How to use `getParameter()` in Struts 2 tag?

Comment: I load in my  jsp page inside  an emplty div another jsp using ajax when I click on link and I want to get in hidden input id passed with  ajax  I can see it  with this instruction  <% 
  String f=request.getParameter("id"); 
  System.out.println(f);       
 %>

Comment: I m traying  this   <s:textfield name="id" value="%{#request.id}"/>   but is not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<s:textfield  value="%{#parameters.id}" />
```

scriptlets as well as JSTL EL not allowed in struts tags attributes. Use OGNL.